# stop function on mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a mousedown function.

```
$('#manRun').mousedown(function(e3) {
    var manID = get_id(this);
    e3.preventDefault();
    $(document).on('mousemove.moveMan, mousemove.slideMan', function(e2) {
       running(e2, runBtn, manID);
    });
});
```

and a mouseup function to stop `running()`

```
$('#manRun').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off('mousemove.moveMan, mousemove.slideMan');
});
```

but the `running()` function does not stop. How can I force `running()` to stop when the mouse is released?

Comment: What is the source of the `running()` function? If it's an animation, you can use `stop()`. Otherwise you'll probably need to store a state flag.

Comment: How does the function 'running' looks like?

Comment: What does `running()` have?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks. it's a continues rotation until the mouse is released. See my edit.

Comment: @Aquiblo thanks. See my edit - I've included the running() function. It's basically a continues rotation when mouse is down. I'm looking to stop it when mouse is up.

Comment: By the moment you wanna click the Stop button, the function would have already stopped isn't it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar: Though the mouse is released the rotation never stops. (it seems like the mouse is still down)

Comment: is there a way to stop css transform rotate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the mouseup was not done on the #manRun object.
Try to attach the handler to the document instead.

```
$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off('mousemove.moveMan, mousemove.slideMan');
});
```